# What takes so much space in my external disk?

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive

My external disk (LaCie) is full! When I look at the individual folders within my disk, I see that only little space is occupied by visible documents. So I displayed the hidden files and found small files and directories that all seem to take very little memory. Looks like about 400GB is occupied by some unknown stuff. However there is a directory called `.trashes`.

[image]

When I click on GetInfo, here is what I see

[image]

And I can wait for a long time but never get an estimate of the size of this directory. I tried to estimate its size via the Terminal:

```
$ du .Trashes
du: .Trashes: Permission denied
```

I tried to delete `.Trashes` but I get this window popping up

[image]

**How can I free space on my external disk?**

I am on OSX Yosemite, Version 10.10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default permission on **.Trashes** do not allow for reading.  Use `sudo du -ch .Trashes` as this will give you both the total and in "Human-readable" output vs. used sectors which you'd then have to convert.

Also you should not delete **.Trashes**, just empty your **Trash**.

If you want to take a graphical look at the contents of the disk use [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com), you might find it interesting and can do some cleanup from within the App too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know there was a trash collector on external disks. How am I suppose to empty the trash or look what is in the trash to eventually put things back? I don't think there is any OS on this disk.

Comment: There doesn't need to be an OS on the disk for there to be a **.Trashes** directory and any file deleted trough **Finder** from that drive should be placed in **.Trashes** directory on that drive.  You can restore what's been deleted by opening up the **Trash** on the **Dock** then **ctrl-click** selecting **Put Back** and **ctrl-click** the **Trash** on the **Dock** and select **Empty Trash** then everything gets deleted from that drive and other drives, internal/external, that are mounted.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand at first place that the documents would be accessible through the Trash of my computer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify when I said "...and **ctrl-click** the **Trash** on the **Dock** and select **Empty Trash** then everything gets deleted from that drive and other drives, internal/external, that are mounted." ... **that is already in the Trash**! :)